# How to implement req-resp in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

We want to implement a req-resp with Kafka in cluster environment.

How to implement the response message delivery on app server node from which the request was sent? The IBM MQ for example has a message selector for this case.
How to implement this in Kafka?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Kafka request/response message exchange pattern is done the same way as in most other messaging systems

http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/conversation/RequestResponse.html

In Kafka there are a few limitations though:

- there are no built in helper functions in the API to set correlation IDs or extract Reply-To addresses. You have to put this information in the messages themselves (i.e in the message key or message value) since Kafka doesn't have custom headers until the upcoming version 0.11 is released
- requests and responses are on regular Kafka topics so they are persistent and in the commit log. There are no temporary topics or non-persistent messages in Kafka. This sounds like a limitation but you will grow to like it because it makes debugging so much easier when all the historical requests and responses are preserved for analytics
- Kafka doesn't have unique client Inboxes or special per-client topics so again you have to use regular topics or individual topic partitions to send request and response messages.

Comment: The problem is that i have for example 4 nodes on consumer

Comment: The problem is that i can't deliver message only on node that sent request. 
I use REQ topic for requests and RESP topic for responses. I have for example 4 nodes on consumer because kafka doesn't have server selectors so all of them will read message from RESP? And only one of nodes will use message and other will n't. What about trafic and idle load for other nodes?

Comment: Then either make 4 response topics or make one response topic with 4 partitions and have each consumer use assign() to listen to just the one partition dedicated to their  responses